# Incorporate PHP Into HTML Form

Tags: php, mysql, html

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm trying to put together functionality which allows an administrator to search for user details in a mySQL database using the email address as the search criteria. Once the search has taken place I would like the 'first' and 'surname' fields in my form to be completed with the record retrieved.

I think the search is working as the form refreshes but it doesn't retrieve any visible information.

I just wondered whether it would be at all possbible please that someone could take a look at my code below and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <?php
        require("phpfile.php");  

        // Opens a connection to a MySQL server  

        $connection=mysql_connect ("hostname", $username, $password);  
        if (!$connection) { die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}  

        // Set the active MySQL database  

        $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);  
        if (!$db_selected) {  
        die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());  
        }  


        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE emailaddress like '%$email%'"); 

        ?> 
        <title>Map!</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="js/gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    <form name="userpasswordreset" id="userpasswordreset" method="post">
        <div class="container">
            <p align="justify">&nbsp;</p>
            <div class="title1">
                <h2>User Details </h2>
            </div>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="26%" height="25"><strong>Email Address</strong></td>
                    <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="70%"><input name="email" type="email" id="email" size="50" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25"><strong>Confirm Email Address </strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input name="conf_email" type="email" id="conf_email" size="50" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td height="25"><label>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" />
                        </label></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25"><strong>First Name </strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input name="fname" type="text" id="fname" size="30" value="<?php echo $row['forename']; ?>" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25"><strong>Last Name </strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input name="lname" type="text" id="lname" size="30"  value="<?php echo $row['surname']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td height="25"><strong>Password</strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" size="30" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25"><strong>Confirm Password </strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input name="conf_pass" type="password" id="conf_pass" size="30" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25"><strong>Password Hint </strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input name="hint" type="text" id="hint" size="30" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </form>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        // Code for validating the form
        var frmvalidator = new Validator("userpasswordreset");
        frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email address"); 
        frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address");
        frmvalidator.addValidation("conf_email","eqelmnt=email", "The confirmed email address is not the same as the email address"); 
    </script>

</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
            <?php
            require("phpfile.php");  

            // Opens a connection to a MySQL server  

            $connection=mysql_connect ("hostname", $username, $password);  
            if (!$connection) { die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}  

            // Set the active MySQL database  

            $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);  
            if (!$db_selected) {  
            die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());  
            }  
            $email  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); // make the value safe for in the query 
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE emailaddress like '%$email%'");  
            $rows   = array(); 

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            $rows[] = $row; 
            } 

            // $rows is now a multi dimensional array with values found by the query 

            ?> 
<title>Map</title>
<script src="js/gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<form name="userpasswordreset" id="userpasswordreset" method="post">
    <p align="justify">&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="title1">
        <h2>Your Details </h2>
    </div>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="26%" height="25"><strong>Email Address </strong></td>
            <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="70%"><input name="email" type="email" id="email" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25"><strong> Confirm Email Address </strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="conf_email" type="email" id="conf_email" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td height="25"><label>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" />
                </label></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25"><strong>First Name </strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="fname" type="text" id="fname" size="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25"><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="lname" type="text" id="lname" size="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25"><strong>Password</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" size="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25"><strong>Confirm Password </strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="conf_pass" type="password" id="conf_pass" size="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25"><strong>Password Hint </strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="hint" type="text" id="hint" size="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    // Code for validating the form
    // Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
    // for details
    var frmvalidator = new Validator("userpasswordreset");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email address"); 
    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("conf_email","eqelmnt=email", "The confirmed email address is not the same as the email address"); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should always check or santize your input before attaching it to a query... What if someone were to enter `'; DROP TABLE userdetails; --` as the email?

Comment: @KileyNaro I'd say thats pretty counterproductive if you're trying to sign up for something :V

Comment: On the serious side, you haven't told us what is going wrong with this code. Also you can sanitize your email with `$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'], $connection);` instead of the current declaration of `$email`.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing the step where you actually run the `mysql_fetch_assoc` function against your query? Just assigning the result of `mysql_query` to the variable `$result` is not enough!

Add something like this after your call to `mysql_query`:

```
if($result)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
}
```

**Edit:** [mysql_fetch_assoc PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 1):

To get all the rows resulted with the query you would need to use a mysql fetch function (there are several).

The preffered method is definitly `mysql_fetch_assoc`

The relevant part of your code would look something like this:

```
$email  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); // make the value safe for in the query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE emailaddress like '%$email%'"); 
$rows   = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

// $rows is now a multi dimensional array with values found by the query
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to help me out with this. I'm pretty new to this, so please forgive the slowness of my uptake with this. I've amended my code to include your text. The form renders, I type in the search criteria, but the only thing that happens is that the page refreshes. I've added the updated code to my original post. Could you possible tell me where I'm going wrong please? Regards

Comment: You still have to do something with `$rows` after you put the result in an array. try `print_r($rows, true);` after the while to see the results gotten from the database. If it didn't yield any results maybe thats because there weren't any results. To doublecheck that just try to execute that query in phpmyadmin with your input email adress and see what comes up. Basic php debuggin really. Read some tutorials :)

Answer (score -2):

Just going over your code breifly, I dont think your passing the value of the email to in your sql query correctly.

try using this.

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE emailaddress like '%" . $email . "%'");`

Comment: PHP allows you to use variables in the middle of a string like that, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Hmmm, did not know, you code do that with PHP, I came from a C# background therefore that looked like a major error to me. Should I keep my answer or delete it ?

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty sure that the problem doesn't lie with email value not being passed, as I've tried this as a separate piece of code and it works fine. What I'm finding a struggle is incorprating the form and php. Many thanks.

Comment: @alykhalid I guess it's up to you to decide whether or not your answer adds value. Your solution is not incorrect, so maybe that's at least worth something...?